# Ghostscript pdf to txt extraction

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript, text-extraction

I'a using Ghostscript 9.18 for windows, and trying to extract text form a pdf file using -sDEVICE=txtwrite My command looks like this:

```
gswin32c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=test.txt test.pdf -c quit
```

But i get always the "Can't find CID for "ArialBlack"
I tried to supply the cid by writing into the fontmap files:

```
/Arial << /FileType /TrueType /Path (c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
/ArialBlack << /FileType /TrueType /Path (c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Identity) 0] >> ;
```

But it seems to not see the entries and still asks for the cids. I know a few versions ago, the font map was just one file, but the devs moved it into the library.
When i use a -sDEVICE=png16m It can normally read the pdf, and print a bmp with the good characters.

Maybe someone knows the anwser?

Comment: That would make sense, because OpenType with TTF data, named `.ttf`, don't *have* CIDs (only obsolete Type1, and modern OpenType fonts with CFF data, can use CIDs) so that's not too surprising. A quick google for the error message you give in your question gives me http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Distributions/Q_26364031.html, which says you need http://corefonts.sourceforge.net installed -- did you search the web first? There's enough hits to [make it unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask this question here.

Comment: Ths is not entirely true. Neither a type 1 font nor a CFF (type 2 font) use CIDs, they use character codes. CIDs are only relevant to CIDFonts. CIDFonts may have type 1 or CFF bsae fonts, but they may also have type 42 base fonts, which are, essentially, TrueType outlines. So a CIDFont with a TTF outline can still be using CIDs.

Answer (score 0):

The default for the Windows version of Ghostscript has, for some time, been to include the support files in the ROM file system, ie as part of the binary executable.

You can get the support files from our Git repository should you need to add them externally on disk (ie you want to modify them).

The fontmap and CIDFmap files can be included using the -I (include path) switch.

Please note that CID is not the same as CIDFont. A CIDFOnt *uses* a CID, it isn't a 'CID', terminology is important here. It seems likely to me that Ghostscript is telling you it can't locate a CIDFont, not a CID.

It sounds like your PDF file uses a CIDFont but doesn't embed it, a very bad practice which likely leads to rendering problems. In the case of txtwrite it will very likely make it impossible to usefully extract the text too.

Comment: You are totally right, thats why i'm trying to include, and parse it. I'll try, Thank You.